# Make bounding box of 3D figure tighter

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bounding-box

I am trying to plot 3 figures using pgfplots next to one-another. To do so, I have created 3 minipages with a with of `0.3\textwidth`, so that there is a bit of room between them.

In each minipage I then plot the following tube (here as an MWE, just a single tube is included)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        name=plot2,
        axis lines=middle, ticks=none,
        width=\textwidth,
        zmin=0, zmax=6,
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=-3, ymax=3,
        xlabel={$X_1$}, ylabel={$X_2$}, zlabel={$t$},
        title={TDSL}
        ]

        \addplot3[%
            opacity = 0.02,
            fill opacity=0.5,
        mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
        surf,
        colormap/hot,
        faceted color=black,
        z buffer = sort,
        samples = 20,
        variable = \u,
        variable y = \v,
        domain = 0:360,
        y domain = 0:5,
        ]
        ({cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {v});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which according to `width=\textwidth,` should take up the entire width, but it does not. Also, the title "TDSL" is very high above the figure, like there is a lot of white-space making the actual figure smaller.

My question is, how can I make the figure have the specified width?

Comment: What do you expect? You put `zmin=0, zmax=6,
        xmin=-3, xmax=3,
        ymin=-3, ymax=3,` and draw the coordinate axes, and that's what you get.

Comment: @user121799 The coordinate axes do not extend to the boundary of the page nor just below the title, which I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand @user121799 (aka @marmot). Everything works as it should. To convince you I added an axis background color and show the result below in the first image which is the result of the following code.

When you are sure you don't need the space to all four directions which would still be in the axis "box" then you can adapt the `bounding box` of the plot. A result is shown below in the second image. The red rectangle is just for debugging purposes to show the adapted bounding box. For details what needs to be done to do so please have a look at the comments in the code.

As you can see in the second image "just" adapting the bounding box does not enlarge the `axis` to the `\textwidth`. Thus you have to adjust the `width` value *manually* so that really the full `\textwidth` is used. I made a commented suggestion for a suitable value as well in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat` level or higher to position axis labels right
        compat=1.8,
        % for simplicity created a style of the original `axis` options
        my axis style/.style={
            width=\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            ticks=none,
            zmin=0, zmax=6,
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,
            ymin=-3, ymax=3,
            xlabel={$X_1$}, ylabel={$X_2$}, zlabel={$t$},
            title={TDSL},
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % (added an axis background color for debugging purposes)
            axis background/.style={
                fill=blue!25,
                opacity=0.5,
            },
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        },
        % for simplicity created a style for the `\addplot` command
        my plot style/.style={
            opacity=0.02,
            fill opacity=0.5,
            mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
            surf,
            faceted color=black,
            z buffer=sort,
            samples=20,
            variable=\u,
            variable y=\v,
            domain=0:360,
            y domain=0:5,
        },
        % a style to (almost) achieve what you want
        my advanced axis style/.style={
            my axis style,
%            % because the `width` doesn't know about "correcting" the bounding box
%            % you have to manually adjust the value to fit your needs (again)
%            width=1.5\textwidth,
            title style={
                % move title above z-axis (arrow)
                at={(axis top)},
                % give the title node a name
                % (which is later used to determine the bounding box of the plot)
                name=axis title,
            },
            % define some helper coordinates to determine the needed/wanted bounding box
            execute at end axis={
                \coordinate (axis left)   at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0,0);
                \coordinate (axis right)  at (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0);
                \coordinate (axis top)    at (axis cs:0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax});
                %
                \coordinate (axis bottom) at (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},0);
                \coordinate (axis lower left)  at (axis bottom -| axis left);
%                % for the top coordinate we need to account for the title
%                % unfortunately at this time the `(axis title)` coordinate is unavailable
%                \coordinate (axis upper right) at (axis title.north -| axis right);
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my axis style]
        \addplot3 [my plot style] ({cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {v});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % don't calculate a bounding box yet
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        % use the modified/advanced axis style here
        \begin{axis}[my advanced axis style]
            \addplot3 [my plot style] ({cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {v});
        \end{axis}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % for debugging only
    \draw [red] (axis lower left) rectangle (axis title.north -| axis right);
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % now we can set the bounding box using the helper coordinates
    \useasboundingbox (axis lower left) rectangle (axis title.north -| axis right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**First page result:**

[image: image showing the result of the first page of above code]

**Second page result:**

[image: image showing the result of the second page of above code]

Comment: +1 (Some users seem to forget that in three dimensions there are three orthogonal directions.... ;-)

Comment: @user121799, to be honest I also first thought if the "offset title" could be a bug in PGFPlots. But I think that was because I (personally) almost never use 3D plots ...